# Displaying data fetched from database in a Button in android

Tags: android-sqlite

I know how to fetch data from sqlite database and display it in a listview. But i want to know how to change the properties of a button according to data fetched from database like color,text etc.
I searched a lot but could not find any relevant answer.
Is it that we can display data from database only in a listview?

**Update**: I have modified my code to display data in a listview as follows:

```
    public class TextAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<Integer>  arr_Id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<String>  arr_Name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String>  arr_Status = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String>  arr_Color = new ArrayList<String>();

    public int i = 0;
    private Context mContext;

    public  TextAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String> array_Name, ArrayList<String> array_Status, ArrayList<String> array_Color) {

        mContext = c;

        arr_Name = array_Name;
        arr_Status = array_Status;
        arr_Color = array_Color;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr_Name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        String status;

        TextView mTextView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            mTextView = new TextView(mContext);
        }

        else {
            mTextView = (TextView)convertView;
        }
        mTextView.setText(arr_Name.get(position) +" "+  arr_Status.get(position) );

        position = 0;

        while (position < arr_Status.size()) {
            status = arr_Status.get(position);
            if (status.equals("Finnished")) {
                mTextView.setBackgroundResource(color.holo_green_dark);
            }
            if (status.equals("Running")) {
                mTextView.setBackgroundResource(color.holo_orange_dark);
            }
            if (status.equals("Stopped")) {
                mTextView.setBackgroundResource(color.holo_red_dark);
            }
            position = position + 1;
//          status = null;
        }

        return mTextView;
    }

}
```

And the **output** is: Fetched data is shown in a list view. Each row has process name and its status(running, finished and stopped). 
Now i want that for Finished process the color of the row be green,for Stopped be red and orange for running one. Here the color of row 1 and row 3 is not as per required. 
Note: Every row is of red color.

please help.

Comment: Hi Cristik! Actually I am trying to create a project in which I will store record of processes. There will be 12 buttons one for each process. Initially I will give each button a process_name, status and color. Color will be based on process status . it will be green if process is finished, red if failed and yellow if running. I will store all this in a database table. Once the database is created, I will fetch the data from database and set the button color according to process_status.

Comment: @cristik , i have updated my question. please see if you can help me. it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because you're looping through all items in a method that is meant for one.

The `getView()` method is executed once for each row of the ListView, which means you should only be looking at one status.

Notice that when you're setting the status text, you're looking at the status at the given position. You need to do that for color, too. Try changing the lines to something like this:

```
String status = arr_Status.get(position);

mTextView.setText(arr_Name.get(position) + " " + status;

if(status.equals("Finished"){
   mTextView.setBackgroundResource(color.holo_green_dark);
} else if(status.equals("Running"){
   mTextView.setBackgroundResource(color.holo_orange_dark);
} else{ // Stopped
   mTextView.setBackgroundResource(color.holo_red_dark);
}
```

The `position` parameter represents the row you are displaying, so there is no need to loop through every row like that.

For that reason, I would assume that the last position has a status of stopped, and that's why every row is red, because at each row you're going through the list, and the status color is set for the last item in the list.

Comment: @Raj not a problem. If this answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers will know what the solution is.